# Custom Metadata Types - RecordType

Tags: apex, custom-metadata

I have created a Custom Metadata Type that has a field with a relationship to EntityDefinition(object).

This [EntityDefinition](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_tooling.meta/api_tooling/tooling_api_objects_entitydefinition.htm) here suggests a field **RecordTypes**, but it is available only in the Tooling API, which does not support Custom Metadata Types. I can work around it by querying the record types with the object name I get from EntityDefinition, but I was thinking if there is a more direct approach to it.

Thoughts, please.

Answer (score 2):

First of all, RecordTypes is a relationship name, not a field:

> Represents the record types defined for this object. Use only in
>   subqueries. This field is available in Tooling API version 34.0 and
>   later. Because this field represents a relationship, use only in
>   subqueries.

Secondly, if you're querying the Custom Metadata Type, you will need *either* a separate query for the record types, or you can use a DescribeSObject call instead. SOQL doesn't support querying the children of parent records (e.g. you cannot say `SELECT (SELECT ... FROM CustomLookup__r.Children__r) FROM Object__c`. Consider using the describe call to save on governor limits.

Comment: Thanks @sfdcfox, I am sure I can do a DescribeSobject and retrieve the recordtypes but is there a way to query it using EntityDefinition's RecordTypes? When I turned on 'Tooling API' and queried cmd types from the dev console, it errored out as Tooling API does NOT support cmd types. From the text you have put in your comments, RecordTypes needs Tooling API, so is it possible to use RecordTypes at all in  combination with cmd types ?

Comment: @ShaliniSF Again, no, SOQL doesn't support this. If you were querying the EntityDefinition directly, using the Tooling API, it would be allowed. But starting from the Custom Metadata Type, you won't be able to do so, since EntityDefinition doesn't exist in the standard SOAP API.

Comment: @sfdxfox, Thanks for the explanation. Looks like Describe is the only way.

Comment: one last question related to EntityDefinition: Can there be duplicates EntityDefiniton  values across records? I am trying to create 2 records with EntityDefiniton value as 'Contact' and the system complains 'Duplicate value on record'. Documenation on Entitydefinition is very limited on the net,so can you pls clarify why there is such restriction?

Comment: @ShaliniSF Yes, it's allowed. However, the name field for each record must be unique, which is what you are probably seeing.